How to refresh a list from GET endpoint after POST request in Rust Yew
The backend on localhost:3040/todos accepts GET and POST requests. In the frontend there is a form with an input field and the submit button to send POST. Underneath the form is the list retrieved by GET. A refresh flag flips when a new POST is sent and triggers use_effect_with with the GET call. The problem is that the GET request is usually faster than POST and I am struggling to find a way to stall the refresh until the POST is processed in the backend.
#[function_component(App)]
fn page_body() -> Html {
    let input_value = use_state(|| String::new());
    let refresh_flag = use_state(|| false);
    let todolist: UseStateHandle<Option<TodoList>> = use_state(|| None);

    let form_onsubmit = {
        let input_value = input_value.clone();
        let refresh_flag = refresh_flag.clone();

        Callback::from(move |e: SubmitEvent| {
            e.prevent_default();

            let new_todo = NewTodo {
                title: String::from(input_value.as_str()),
            };

            wasm_bindgen_futures::spawn_local(async move {
                let todos_url: String = format!("http://localhost:3040/todos");
                let data_serialized = serde_json::to_string_pretty(&new_todo).unwrap();

                let request = Request::post(&todos_url)
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .body(wasm_bindgen::JsValue::from(&data_serialized))
                    .send().await
                    .unwrap()
                    .text().await
                    .unwrap();
            });
            input_value.set(String::from(""));
            refresh_flag.set(!*refresh_flag);
        })
    };

    { // do this block on page load and when refresh flag is flipped

        let todolist = todolist.clone();
        use_effect_with(refresh_flag, move |_| {
            wasm_bindgen_futures::spawn_local(async move {
                let todos_url: String = format!("http://localhost:3040/todos");

                let fetched_todos: TodoList = Request::get(&todos_url)
                    .send().await
                    .unwrap()
                    .json().await
                    .unwrap();

                todolist.set(Some(fetched_todos));
            });
        });
    }

    html! {
        <div>
            <div>
            <form onsubmit={form_onsubmit}>
                <input 
                    type="text"
                    value={(*input_value).clone()}
                    oninput={form_oninput}/>
                <input type="submit" value="Create TODO" />
            </form>
            </div>
            <div>
            <ul>
                {
                match todolist.as_ref() {
                    Some(tdl) => tdl
                        .todos.iter().map(|todo| {
                            html! {
                                <li>
                                <TodoComponent todo={todo.clone()}/>
                                </li>
                            }
                        })
                        .collect(),
                    None =>{html! {<>{"No data yet"}</>} },
                }
            }
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}

